# How get Cognito users list in JSON-format

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm going to backup of my Cognito users with Lambda but I can't get Cognito users list in JSON-format with boto3. I do:

```
import boto3
import os
import json
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

COGNITO_POOL_ID = os.getenv('POOL_ID')
S3_BUCKET = os.getenv('BACKUP_BUCKET')
ENV_NAME = os.getenv('ENV_NAME')
filename = ENV_NAME + "-cognito-backup.json"
REGION = os.getenv('REGION')

cognito = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name=REGION)
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler (event,context):
    try:
        response = (cognito.list_users(UserPoolId=COGNITO_POOL_ID,AttributesToGet=['email_verified','email']))['Users']
        data = json.dumps(str(response)).encode('UTF-8')
        s3object = s3.Object(S3_BUCKET, filename)
        s3object.put(Body=(bytes(data)))
    except ClientError as error:
        print(error)
```

But get one string and I'm not sure that is JSON at all:

```
[{'Username': 'user1', 'Attributes': [{'Name': 'email_verified', 'Value': 'true'}, {'Name': 'email', 'Value': 'user1@xxxx.com'}], 'UserCreateDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 10, 13, 13, 34, 457000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'UserLastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 10, 13, 13, 34, 457000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'Enabled': True, 'UserStatus': 'FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD'}]
```

I need something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Username": "user1",
    "Attributes": [
      {
        "Name": "email_verified",
        "Value": "true"
      },
      {
        "Name": "email",
        "Value": "user1@xxxx.com"
      }
    ],

    "Enabled": "true",
    "UserStatus": "CONFIRMED"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import ast
import json

print(ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(response)))
```

For the dict response from the SDK?

Edit: Just realized since the `list_users` SDK also UserCreateDate object, json.dumps will complain about the transformation due to the datatime value of the UserCreateDate  key. If you get that off, this will work without the ast module -

```
import json
data = {'Username': 'Google_11761250', 'Attributes': [{'Name': 'email', 'Value': 'abc@gmail.com'}],'Enabled': True, 'UserStatus': 'EXTERNAL_PROVIDER'}
print((json.dumps(data)))
```

```
> {"Username": "Google_1176125910", "Attributes": [{"Name": "email", "Value": "123@gmail.com"}], "Enabled": true, "UserStatus": "EXTERNAL_PROVIDER"}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check the output type by using

```
type(output)
```

I guess that it can be `list` type, so you can convert it into `JSON` and **prettyprint** by using:

```
print(json.dumps(output, indent=4))
```